# strtok with comma spaces and tab

Tags: c, strtok

So consider this string:

```
1,2.2, 3.5 ,6,     7.7
```

And i want to separate each number, so until now i try this:

```
void readuserinput(char *ch)
{
    char* buffer;
    buffer = strtok(ch, ",");
    while (buffer) {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        buffer = strtok(NULL, ",");
        while (buffer && *buffer == '\040')
            buffer++;
    }
}
```

But this ignored the`Tab` and print the number `7.7` with `tab` before.

Comment: Your loop to skip leading space should add a check for the string terminator, and probably use [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) to check for any white-space character. And you should probably do it *before* you print the value!

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you write `'\040'` when you can simply write `' '`? It's probably not clear in everyone's mind that the ASCII code of SPACE in octal is 40. But anyway using `isspace` as suggested is even better.

Comment: Can i have code example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [strtok documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) you can specify multiple delimiters to it. So you don't have to manually deal with whitespaces. `strtok` will do that for you:

```
void readuserinput(char *ch)
{
    ch = strtok(ch, ", \t");
    while (ch)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ch);
        ch = strtok(NULL, ", \t");
    }
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh he said he has tabs in the string.